# GWT Java how to convert List<File> to something the client side can use?

Tags: java, gwt, google-drive-api

EDITED

This is probably a stupid question but I can't figure it out.  I am using Java with GWT in Eclipse to create a RPC application to get google drive metadata.  All is working (I am getting back the metadata on the server side) but I can't figure out how to pass this data over to the client side so that I can display it.

I am getting a list of metadata for google drive docs as follows:

```
public List<File> getFromRemoteServer()
        throws HowToListingException {

List<File> lista = null;

try {
    lista = retrieveAllFiles(getDriveService("email@xxxx.org"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return lista;

}
```

My question is, how do I change the List type to something that the client side can use? i.e what do I put here (fill in the blank)?  And how would I convert lista to that type?

```
    asyncSvc.getFromRemoteServer( {
        new AsyncCallback<____________>() {
    }
```

A bit more hopefully clarifying information:

I know to make this work I have to serialize the File object.  I'm just not sure if I can or where to put this.
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#serialize

In the server side implementation, I am using this File:

import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

Which I need to use to have this code work properly:

```
public static Drive getDriveService(String userEmail) throws GeneralSecurityException,
    IOException, URISyntaxException {

  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
      .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
      .build();
  Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
  return service;
}

    private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {

        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = null;
        try {
                  request = service.files().list();
                  FileList files = request.setQ("'"+"0B9lpwZZfxxxxxxxxVeEJFR3M"+"' in parents and trashed=false").execute();
                  result.addAll(files.getItems());          
                  request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
                } 
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                request.setPageToken(null);
              }

        for(File f:result)
          {
              System.out.println(f.getTitle());
              System.out.println(f.getOwners());
              System.out.println(f.getModifiedDate());

          }
        return result;
      }
```

The problem comes when I try to use

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
```

on the client side in the synchronous and asynchronous interfaces and the client code (entry point).  I get the error message about "did you forget to inherit a required module - no code found for this import."  I am assuming that means I can't use this on the client side.  I've tried to import java.io.File instead but then I get messages that I can't convert between the two types.

I feel like I am close, I just need a push in the right direction.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass classes that implement Serializable. I don't know what `File` class is, but if it's not serializable, you cannot pass it using RPC.

If `File` implements Serializable, you can pass `ArrayList<File>` to AsyncCallback. Note that with GWT it is always better to use a specific implementation (ArrayList instead of List) in order to reduce the compiled code.

Comment: Ok so I'm pretty new at this and trying to teach myself as I go.  I don't think I asked the question very well.  I'm going to edit my question to hopefully provide more clarification.  You and keuleJ may very well be giving me the right answer and I just don't know how to implement it.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Design your own class that contains the info you need to display. And maybe a unique path. Send that class, which should be Serializable to the client.